# I used acid to clean rust from parts on resto project. Should I worry about hydrogen embrittlement?

Tags: folding-bicycle, steel, rust, restoration, fastener

I have a 1970s U-folder type bike which was very crusty when I acquired it. I removed the rust by soaking the parts in lemon juice for between 24-72 hours, depending on the part. Something I wasn't even aware of at the time was hydrogen embrittlement or how it could be caused by industrial pickling.

Would exposure to such a weak acid be cause for alarm in more critical components like the hinge pin? If a replacement would be needed, should I get something made of alloy steel or would a low carbon steel pin be acceptable?

Comment: I’m worried this might be a little too materials-science-y for this Stack. But I hope you find a good answer.

Comment: FWIW, I would expect the lemon juice (pH 2-3) to be much less of a problem than typical industrial acids (pH 0-1, for example phosphoric acid around 0.2).  2 pH difference is a factor of 100 less hydrogen ions, so I would expect comparably lessened effect.  And the steel of the bike is probably not hardened, which would also reduce the expected embrittlement.

Comment: FYI, soaking chains in many non-aerospace degreasers like Simple Green (the standard formulation; I think it has a pH of 9.3) is thought to be enough to risk hydrogen embrittlement.